# Xslt creating an exclusion map and iterating with function

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to do something that I thought would be simple in xslt and there may be an easier way to accomplish this task. What I want to do is to create a map in a template for exclusions and then iterate through all the nodes and exclude the nodes that match certain criteria.

This is an example of the input I am trying to process. There is a large number of these records from the database. My goal is to create a simple editable map at the top of the stylesheet that a person can edit to add a rule for a record exclusion. So for example they could make an exclusion based on order_id or product_id. The map would contain the node path as the key and the value of the node that would match the rule for exclusion.

```
<row>
    <row_number>14122</row_number>
    <order_id>14590</order_id>
    <order_item_seq_id></order_item_seq_id>
    <status_id></status_id>
    <customer_id>14590</customer_id>
    <company_name>Customer 1</company_name>
    <main_contact_name>Example Customer</main_contact_name>
    <email_address>example@company.org</email_address>
    <country_code xsi:nil="true" />
    <local_number></local_number>
    <address1></address1>
    <address2></address2>
    <city></city>
    <state_province_geo_id></state_province_geo_id>
    <postal_code></postal_code>
    <site_id></site_id>
    <company_location_name></company_location_name>
    <location_contact_name></location_contact_name>
    <site_main_number></site_main_number>
    <site_email_address></site_email_address>
    <site_country_code></site_country_code>
    <site_local_number></site_local_number>
    <site_address1></site_address1>
    <site_address2></site_address2>
    <site_city></site_city>
    <site_state_province_geo_id></site_state_province_geo_id>
    <site_postal_code></site_postal_code>
    <type_id>CUSTOMER</type_id>
    <product_id>PROD_1</product_id>
    <service_profile_item_seq_id></service_profile_item_seq_id>
    <quantity>0</quantity>
    <unit_price>0.00</unit_price>
    <seller_sales_code>Example</seller_sales_code>
    <entry_sales_code></entry_sales_code>
</row>
```

Here is my map that I want to use for exclusions. The idea here is that the key is an xpath with a value.

```
<xsl:variable name="exclusions">
    <exclusion key="customer_id">49510</exclusion>
    <exclusion key="customer_id">49673</exclusion>
    <exclusion key="production_id">PROD_1</exclusion>
</xsl:variable>
```

I was hoping to create a function that I could use to test to see if the node contains the value to exclude. **Note** I don't know if this is even well formed but I ran into a problem of returning false as a default value. I don't know how to return a default value if the check does not find the matching criteria. I am sure there is a better way of accomplishing this task.

```
<xsl:function name="isExclusion" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="toCheck" />
    <xsl:for-each select="exclusions/exclusion">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="toCheck/@key = '.'">
                <xsl:value-of select="true()" />
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

This may not be the correct solution but any advice would be greatly appreciated. I really would like to even create a function that prunes the input for the exclusions before processing. Otherwise I have to call the isExclusion multiple times in my code. I have searched quite a bit for an example of this kind of solution but have not been able to find a good example that will hlep me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit and make sure you use e.g. `$toCheck` if you want to reference the parameter you have declared as `<xsl:param name="toCheck" />`. Also it is not clear whether the `select="exclusions/entry"` is meant to reference the variable `exclusions`, in that case you would need `select="$exclusions/entry"`. Generally, in a function, if you want to return a boolean value based on a condition, I would simply use e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="$toCheck/@key = '.'"/>`. The main focus is on using `xsl:sequence` and the boolean expression in the `select` attribute.

Comment: Martin, thank you so much for your help. I had changed the map to use exclusion from entry but had not changed the template. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Martin, I updated the question with an answer that I am testing. Does this make sense and do you see any issues?

Comment: I am suggesting to make the function body something like `<xsl:sequence select="$exclusions/exclusion/@key = $toCheck/@key"/>`. That particular expression I have written is probably not what you want as so far I am not sure about the check you want to make.

Comment: I updated the question with actual input that would be passed into the stylesheet. I think my problem is that I can't figure out how to do a simple for loop and then return true if the node is found in the list of exclusions. Maybe it's not possible to solve the problem the way I am going about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return a boolean value, simply use `xsl:sequence` with a `select` attribute which is a boolean expression.

Don't use `xsl:value-of`, as both `<xsl:value-of select="true()"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="false()"/>` create a text node with a non-empty string value which your `as="xs:boolean"` would convert to the boolean value `true`.

Comment: Martin, I think you are giving me the answer I need but I am confused about how to implement it. I have tried creating a simple <xsl:text> node and true to it but I am getting an error "XPTY0004: An empty sequence is not allowed as the result of function". This makes sense because I am not always returning a value. I am sorry but I am confused on how a sequence would help me in this case. I have read up on sequence's here http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/sequence.html but am not sure how this would help me to return a true or false if it is found/ not found.